# Can the door to a kitchen be locked?

Tags: business

I was just wondering if it is legal for a restaurant to lock the doors of a kitchen where food is being prepared. The door can be opened from the inside

It would seem that in case of a fire in the kitchen, the door would not open from the outside, creating a safety hazard.

Thanks for the info.

Comment: In what state/country?

Comment: Why is it necessary for the door to open from *outside* in a fire? If there's a fire in the kitchen, no one should be entering it except firefighters (who are trained, equipped, and routinely required to break down locked doors). This could be an issue if the kitchen is part of an exit path used to meet fire code or marked as a fire exit, but absent that I'm not sure why people outside the kitchen need to be able to enter.

Comment: Such safety rules vary a good deal in different jurisdictions, but the most common rule is that people may not be locked **in** when a fire happens. See https://www.famous-trials.com/trianglefire/971-trianglecodes and https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-laws-law-came-out-both-triangle-shirtwaist-675233 Many places use "panic bars" which unlock when pushed from the inside, and those seem to comply with codes in many areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is a difference between emergency exits and ordinary exits

Building codes (which vary by jurisdiction) require egress routes for use in an emergency. These exits are quite often different from the ones used in non emergency situations. Indeed, they are usually different exits, that is, the emergency exits are *only* used in emergencies and the normal exits are *not* emergency exits.

Emergency exits are *usually* one-way - they allow egress but prevent access. Think of a cinema complex - you can enter through the front door but there will be several emergency exits which are locked from the outside.

Providing the locked door is not blocking an egress route, it’s fine.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, the laws vary from place to place, but typically the laws talk about how to mark fire exits, not exactly when they should be locked or unlocked.

Knowing exactly when every door should be locked or unlocked would be impossible based on the amount of circumstances that could be happening behind those doors.

Follow the laws on how the exits should be marked.

Comment: This is incorrect. In many jurisdictions laws require that emergency exists be open for people to leave a building whenever the building has people in it, or in some cases when customers are present. In some cases non-emergency exits must also remain open under specific conditions, such as when the place is open for business.

Comment: He said it opens from the inside.

Comment: The question said that the door opens from inside. This answer did not. And in some jurisdictions non-emergency doors are legally required to be open for both egress and ingress at particular times or in particular conditions, contrary to this answer. My downvote stands.

Comment: What jurisdiction says a door must open from the outside?

Comment: I have seen, in a number of retail establishments in different US states, signs stating "This door must remain unlocked while customers are present." I have seen this in MI, NY, NJ, MD at least.

Comment: That means from the inside man.

Comment: I believe that you are mistaken.

Comment: I haven't lived everywhere, but I know 100% for sure that in IL anyway I am not.

Comment: And you offer no proof that I am mistaken.

Comment: You asserted in an answer that "laws talk about how to mark fire exits, not exactly when they should be locked or unlocked." statements in answers that are challenged should be supported by evidence. Downvote stands.

Comment: It says laws vary from place to place and you can't produce any evidence that the law works the way you say.

Comment: The Maryland [Montgomery County Fire safety code](https://www.montgomerycountymd.gov/frs-ql/Resources/Files/Accreditation/ACR/ACR_2017/NEW_2016_COMCOR_Fire_Safety_Code-DPS_Director.pdf)  provides in item 22.00.07.76
"all stairway doors must be unlocked simultaneously without unlatching upon a signal from the fire command center."

Comment: The [New York City code Title 27 / Subchapter 6](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dob/downloads/bldgs_code/bc27s6.pdf)
§[C26-604.5] 27-372 requires that:  "Doors  providing  access  to  areas  ofrefuge  shall  be  kept  unlocked  at  all  times  when  anyfloor area served by the area of refuge is occupied."

Comment: Neither of those say that the are describing whether you can or can't lock it from the outside. Any reasonable person would infer those codes mean that the door should be usable to people inside the building.  I'm not trying to be mean about it, but what you are saying is clearly not how most reasonable judges would interpret the building codes.